# Setting different colours to the same character of a label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, mask

How to set two different colours to the same character of a label (like NBC APP's schedule date selection. in centre selected box, the text colour has been changed regardless of character range of the label).

Sample image:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but you can probably achieve this by:

- Create two views, each containing a label, both with the full text.
- Change the color accordingly.
- Put the second view (with the blue text) below the first one (grey text).
- Change the frame size of your first view so only half of the text is displayed.
- If no truncating happens to the text, you should end up with the above effect.